# Saturn's moons - getting a stable harmonic model for Mimas and Encyladus

Tags: orbital-motion, computational-physics, planets, software, harmonics

I have built a HTML/Javascript solar system model. It is working well with real time animation.

https://abetz-rouse.com.au/planetarium

I don't want to get into the deficiencies of my choice of platform - let's just say it is a very accessible application and the model can be run on any computer that has Chrome or Firefox.

To initialise the positions of planets and moons I have just used some basic orbital parameters that can be found easily, but initial positions are just arbitrary.

If you check out my model with a modern browser you can zoom into the moons of Saturn by selecting 'Saturn' on the right and using the zoom. Play the model, and you will see the moons move very fast - the bodies move between points in straight lines, so the inner ones will appear to move more like electrons than planets! Don't worry, there are about 500 calculation points per day between theses satellites, but only 4 animation points.

I am happy that the mathematical model is working fine, but Mimas is slowly moving outwards and Enceladus is being drawn inwards.

I understand that orbital harmonics depends on the ratio of orbital periods, but it seems I am missing some subtleties here. I have initialised the moons as all 60° (π/3) behind each other from inner to outer hoping that would give the best chance of harmonic stability. I am wondering if I need to point the ellipse major axis for each moon in a particular direction to stop this orbital decay?

You can run it by visiting the URL above (in a modern browser), but to modify parameters you will need to pull down the file and pull down the two javascript libraries into a js folder above the directory you download to, you can then run it anywhere, and make any modifications you like. At line 667 there is the list of planetary bodies I have inserted into the model (in json) - note: moon positions are in Lunar distances, planet positions in Astronomical units, and velocity is entered as relative to circular orbit speed for the given position. It is easy to play with different initial parameters to test different scenarios, so if someone thinks they know how to get Saturn's moons behaving nicely, please help me!

By the way - this is all free to re-use and copy.

Comment: It isn’t clear what your mathematical model of their motion is. Are you integrating the differential equations of motion, or just moving moons along ellipses whose focus (~ the moon’s planet) moves along an ellipse, or something else?

Comment: A few comments: i) I do not understand whether you face a physics problem or a computational problem. Your code looks impressive, and I could not figure out which algorithm you are using for integrating the planetary evolution. ii) initialization may be a problem; however, you can check by using accurate 3D positions and coordinates from NASA site: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi  ; iii) probably SE Computational Science could be a better site for your question unless you could focus better on a physical issue.

Comment: It is using an integral calculus method, like a Taylor series to four derivatives, if I was just assuming two body ellipses then I would get perfect but rather mundane results!

Comment: I adjust the number of calculations between each body according to the 4th derivative error. Where moons interact a psuedo-three body process is applied as the tidal effect makes the calculations go askew if you don't take that into account. All the interactions are brought together to make a daily integral step.